# jsf: get id from rest url or rewrite url

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

Currently I rewrite url as below

```
.addRule(Join.path("/users").to("/views/user/index.jsf"))
```

But now I need to rewrite url which includes numbers(user id). For example, if I have url as `/users/1` or `/users/200`, etc. I need to match them to view `/views/user/profile.jsf`

Similarly, I also need to rewrite urls `/users/1/edit` or `/users/200/edit` to `/views/user/edit.jsf`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is working for me now but not sure if this is the correct way of doing things.

First I rewrite the url as `.addRule(Join.path("/users/{id}").to("/views/user/show.jsf"))`

and I make the url as

```
<h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Show</f:facet>
                <h:outputLink value="/users/#{user.id}">Show</h:outputLink>
            </h:column>
```

This generate the url as `/users/1` or `/users/200` etc.

Now I can access the user id parameter from jsf page `show.xhtml` as  `<h:outputText value="#{param['id']}" />`

I can also access the parameter from bean as

```
public void show(){
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
            getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String user_id = params.get("id");
}
```

Or I can also do something like this

in `show.xhtml` as

```
<ui:param name="user" value="#{userController.show(param['id'])}" />

Name: #{user.firstName}
```

and in `userController` as

```
public User show(Integer id){
    user = userService.findById(id);
    return user;

}
```